# How to make the value from my form toggle instead of just showing it as soon as the page reloads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and I want the value that was input in the form to be toggled. I am currently using this code. But instead of just showing what my users put in the form, I want them to be able to toggle the photo that they chose. So when they press the photo, the information they've placed will show and if they click it again, it'll hide. Thank you!

```
    albumgallery.innerHTML += `<figure><img src='img/albumcover.jpeg' width='150px' alt='chosen PC card'/>
    <figcaption>Title: ${title.value}</figcaption>
    <figcaption>Artist: ${artist.value}</figcaption>
    <figcaption>Genre: ${genre.value}</figcaption>
    </figure>`;
```

If that doesn't make sense, please let me know and I'll explain further.

Comment: why not you have a DIV with information and hide show on click, i mean, hide the pic or animate as flip? no?

Comment: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/OJEegvo?editors=1111 can you have a look at this?

Comment: @Louise, if any of the answers solved your problem, don't miss to accept that answer and don't forget to reward your helper with Acceptance of his/her answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
let image = document.querySelector("img");
let flag = true;
function toggle() {
  flag = !flag;
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll("figcaption");
  elements.forEach((elem) => {
    flag ? (elem.style.display = "none") : (elem.style.display = "block");
  });
}
image.addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

Live demo here: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/OJEegvo?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want

```
$('#imgElephant').click(function ()
  {
    console.log('hello');
   $('figcaption').toggle("slow",function(){ console.log("complete");} );
  },
  function ()
   {
    console.log('goodbye');
    $('figcaption').toggle("slow",function(){ console.log("complete");} );
  });
```

JS[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z4fb03t/)